# How do I calculate the maximum temperature of an exothermic NaOH reaction in water?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, thermodynamics, energy, heat, temperature

As the title suggests, let's say I want to make a 1 L 14M NaOH solution. For this I'd need:

- (14 mol/ L) x 1 L x (39.99 g / mol ) = 559.86 g NaOH(s) {solute}
- ~1 L H2O (approx) {solvent}

The dissolution of NaOH is exothermic and the solution gets VERY hot (I physically measured over 70°C+). I want to predict the maximum and transient temperatures of the chemical system. Assuming the standard enthalpy of formation at 298.15 K / 25°C (ΔfH) for the following species:

- ΔfH_NaOH(s) = -425.6 kJ/mol
- ΔfH_Na+(aq) = -240.1 kJ/mol
- ΔfH_OH-(aq) = -230 kJ/mol

The total enthalpy/heat of reaction via Hess' Law is:

-(-425.6 kJ/mol) + (-240.1 kJ/mol) + (-230 kJ/mol) = -44.5 kJ/mol

Using that number along with the following thermodynamic properties:

- Molar Heat Capacity of NaOH(s) = 59.5 J/mol·K
- (If necessary assume a standard 1L glass beaker with a thermal conductivity = 1 W/m·K)
- Initial ambient temperature of 298 K.

How can I determine the max temperature that the solution will reach? I've tried doing calculations myself with these constants but I get answers with units [mol·K] via:

**EDIT 1:**

559.86 g NaOH x (1 mol NaOH / 39.99 g NaOH) x (-44,500 J / 1 mol NaOH) x (1 mol NaOH·K / 59.5 J)
= -10,471 mol NaOH·K = -10744.15 mol NaOH·°C

...which doesn't make sense as the answer should just be in temperature i.e. [K]. The number I calculated is also ridiculously high and obviously wrong. What am I missing?

Comment: How do you get a number in mol×K? Need to see the calculations.

Comment: @OscarLanzi refer to the newest edit cheers. I know the answer will likely involve some sort of integration for the transient/dynamic temperature but I'm not really sure how...

Comment: The heat capacity of water is different from the heat capacity of the NaOH solution. So the same amount of Joules will produce a different temperature increase in the beginning and at the end of the dissolution. So you would have to know the formula describing how the heat capacity of the solution changes with the concentration. This is not an easy task.

Comment: @Maurice thanks for the comment. Could you please elaborate on this, maybe even in a reply? I'm very determined to get to the bottom of this. I originally thought this sort of problem would be easily solvable especially in industry where I'd imagine scientists/engineers (etc.) would need to figure out the right thermo-resistant materials for building a reactor to avoid overheating (etc.).

Comment: Note that 14 M NaOH means 14 mol of NaOH (about 560 g) in 1 L of the solution, not to be added into 1 L of water. Just to be sure you are aware of it. // There is big problem of combination of 2 experimentally determined nonlinear quantities: ratio dependent dissolution enthalpy and ratio dependent specific heat.

Comment: @Hendrix 13. I am not familiar with this problem, and I don't know whether a formula  exists for describing how the specific heat of the solution changes with increasing $\ce{NaOH}$ concentration. Anyway you should also take into account the heat capacity of the container. if I were you, I would not make any difficult calculations. I would just try and measure the temperature in the container.

Comment: @Maurice I've measured it in the beaker and found it to go over 60°C+. I want to upscale from beaker to batch reactor which means I'll have a much higher NaOH input feedstock and higher max temperature. Are you suggesting that if there's no numerical model way to estimate the max temperature of the reactor with a given NaOH mass I'm better off just conservatively choosing thermo-resistant materials/metals for the reactor?

Comment: Yes. I am suggesting that no numerical model will estimate the max temperature of the reactor, and that the knowledge of the molar heat capacity of NaOH is useless. The heat capacity of NaOH ($1.5 J g^{-1}K^{-1}$) is nearly negligible with respect to the heat capacity of water ($4.18 J g^{-1} K^{-1}$} and aqueous solutions (unknown). You have not mentioned the mass of NaOH and water to be used. Is it $1 g$ ? $1 kg$? $100 kg$ ? Less ? More ?

Comment: don't forget the $\ce{HO- + H+ -> H2O}$ reaction, especially if your solution is buffered.

Comment: Yes for the reactor it'd be around say 50kg. Regardless it won't matter if there's no numerical solution or approximation. This is very surprising and very unexpected that there's no solution here.

Comment: I don't say there is no numerical solution. I only state the I don't know whether there is such a formula.

Comment: Preparation of 1 kg of solution is unusual. It is not possible to prepare 1 kg of 14 M NaOH without the knowledge of 14 M NaOH density, which could be found or interpolated in tabelated data. The easiest way is to prepare 1 L of 14 M solution and then to take 1 kg of it.

Comment: @Hendrix13 Chemical engineers may have some empirical formula or charts for that, but I have not found any. As the integral dissolution enthalpy is empirical data dependent on concentration. Eventually tabelated or calculated data is for infinite dilution.

Comment: The easiest way is to measure temperature by test dissolution, then to measure or estimate solution heat capacity and heat capacity of the vessel where is it would be prepared.

Comment: @Poutnik thanks for the great reply! That last comment seems to be the way to go I think at this point as I'm also asking some professors and industry contacts. Could you please expand upon your last comment in a reply so I can understand it easier? At this point I suspect it'd be the accepted answer.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134366/discussion-on-question-by-hendrix13-how-do-i-calculate-the-maximum-temperature-o).

Comment: As someone with bachelors in both chemistry and chemical engineering, I can tell you that this sort calculation was not focused on in my chemistry courses, but is an important and standard exercise in multiple chemical engineering courses. If you search for "Adiabatic temperature rise", you can find calculation methodologies at varying levels of approximation.

Comment: This is very useful! If you did more work on the industrial 48-50% to 25% operation I'd like to discuss with you or read your final report. On the plant we use a fin fan to cool it after mixing, but winter can be challenging in terms of freezing of caustic since this is also an interesting non linear curve and should be considered for design of applications.

Comment: Hi @MorneBooysen, yes freezing caustic was a pain for us too. I'm unable to message you on here, but feel free to +1 the question if it helps and message me on linkedin at Ramon Skane (Perth, Australia) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking to a very experienced industrial chemist about this he helped me reach a very interesting answer which I believe is correct. I've provided good detail below to help anyone else with similar questions.

**1. The Theory/Logic:**

The first pointer he mentioned is that the molar heat of solution of NaOH in water does **not** hold true at NaOH concentrations approaching 14M NaOH, this is because as NaOH (s) dissolves it can form NaOH.nH2O as well as Na+ and OH- with (n = 1,2,,3.5,4...7 (etc.)) all depending on the concentration of NaOH. Refer below to page 11 of the Dow Caustic Manual:

[image: Change in molar heat dissolution wrt [NaOH]]

This effect really kicks in when [NaOH] reaches > 20%wt and results in less temperature rise than expected from calculations when [NaOH] > 20wt%.
As an example experiment form literature validating this, refer to the graphic below from "Experimental Study of the Thermal Effect of the Dissolution Reaction for some Alkalis and Salts with Natural Mixing an Forced Stirring" below showing starting temperatures of Starting temperature 10°C and ending temperature close to 80°C thus a 70°C increase making 38%w/w NaOH. This is much closer to what I've seen in the lab when I've done it.

[image: Literature NaOH temperature profile of variable concentration.]

Combining all this theory, I made the following graph below which outlines the change in molar heat dissolution and hydrate formation with changing [NaOH]. It can be seen that the actual molar heat of dissolution I should be using is not -44.5 kJ/mol but really around -30 kJ/mol.

[image]

**2. The Calculation/Application:**

Along with the above assumptions, also assume that:

- Specific Heat Capacity of Water (Cp,H2O(l)) = 4.184 kJ/kg°C
- Solute Mass = (14 mol/ L) x 1 L x (39.99 g / mol ) = 559.86 g NaOH(s)
- Assume 14M NaOH density is 1460 g/L
- Solvent Mass = (1460 - 559.86)g = 900.14 g (i.e. NaOH is 38.3wt%)

Dissolving 559.86g NaOH (for 14 M) in 1L of water produces an enthalpy change (∆H) equivalent to -30kJ/mol x 14mol = - 420 kJ.

Taking the equation ∆H = mCp∆T and rearranging to solve for
∆T = ∆H/(m x Cp) = -420 kJ / (1.46 kg x 4.184 kJ/kg) = 68°C increase
Therefore, Tf = Ti + ∆T = (24.85 +68)°C = 93°C

This value is much closer to the value obtained in the experiment graphic above as well as what I originally measured in the lab.

I would suspect that if I made the 14M NaOH solution in a 1L pyrex beaker with open top, losses from the conduction of heat into beaker, radiation from beaker walls and conduction loses from liquid surface would keep the liquid closer to 70-80°C.

If the 14M was made in a larger quantity e.g. 100L in a 200L capacity drum, I would expect that the true 68°C increase in temperature over ambient to be realized as losses would be small relative to the amount of heat generated. Also, I acknowledge that a more accurate result would come about by measuring the actual density of 14M NaOH and using in calculations.

Many plastics are not capable of holding liquids at 93°C especially if their density is 1.5kg/L so, as another inferential answer to my question, using a metal container is certainly preferable.

**EDIT1 & UPDATE:**

Just thought I'd add the extrapolated curves I got based on these calculations by changing concentration.
The graph below includes a tail at the end after a smoothing of data series, I believe this is from the 6th degree polynomial I used to extrapolate the heat of dissolution trend where R^2 =/= 1. So for concentrations below, say 19, with this method seem more accurate. Assumes an overall 95% heat transfer efficiency.

[image: Maximum Temperature Profile of Pellet-based NaOH Solution at Varying Concentrations]

Adding more practicality to this (which is what I'm aiming for with my research), is the graph below used with industrial "50% caustic" (my product's spec actually had a 49.9% alkalinity) which can be diluted with water to achieve various concentrations. Here instead I'm assuming 100% efficiency.

[image]

Hope this makes sense and is useful to others as it has been for me!

Comment: Why do you insist on dissolving in 1 L water when you just determined the water mass 900 g? Another mistake is considering the solution has the specific heat capacity of water while significant part of it is not water. //  Note that the molar ratio=f(conc %) can be formulated as the exact function. // See [meta.stackexchange.com: new feature table support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support) for easy syntax to format the text into a table, which is preferred to screen captures or scanned images.

Comment: I suggest using some inert object (e.g. from stainless steel or glass) and measure its heat capacity in a water bath with different initial water and object temperatures. Then measure the heat capacity and  calculate the specific heat capacity of the target 14 M NaOH  by doing the same with this solution. // Be aware the higher volumes mean higher peak temperature due slower heat dissipation due lower surface/mass ratio.

Comment: I am sorry your "answer" from March 14 is not easy to understand. For example, your first table gives values of $\Delta H$ for the dissolution of 1 mole NaOH in $n$ mol water. But this $\Delta H$ values is useless it the heat capacity of the solution is not given. And this heat capacity is changing during the dissolution process. Why not give the maximum  temperature change instead of the $\Delta H$ values ? Second you do not explain the difference between natural mixing and forced stirring. Natural mixing is probably done at the bottom of a beaker. But the result will not be homogeneous.

Comment: Note that the first table and figure are from the Dow Caustic manual. It's from their experiments I've just used some of their results to build correlations.